# Suppose that H is a subgroup of K. Then $ (G:H)=(G:K)(K:H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group and let H and K be subgroups of G.

Suppose that H is a subgroup of K. Then $ (G:H)=(G:K)(K:H)$

So I have to prove that the number of cosets of H in G is equal to the number of cosets of K in G multiplied by the number of cosets of H in K.

But we also know that $(G:H)$ = $\frac{order(G)}{order(H)}$. If I just use this formula, it is very easy to prove the statement by just equating the two and cancelling out the order of K.

But I feel like using that formula is not enough to prove this statement. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "But I feel like using that formula is not enough to prove this statement."  Why not?  That sounds right to me.

Comment: You should use the fact that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ then $a\mid c,$ together with Lagrange's Theorem